# IIS: Getting the right SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, iis

I have this API, which i'm trying to get an SSL certificate for which I can use in IIS. However, the only certificate I can get my hands on, is a LocalHost Certificate. This wouldn't be a problem if I wanted to use localhost, however, i'm making a production application. When i'm trying to open this API, which is hosted on IIS, I get the following error:

> Your connection is not private.
> Cybercriminals are trying to get your data from **my ip**. The server can't prove that this is **my ip**. The certificate of the server is originated from localhost. This can be a faulty configuration, or an attacker trying to intercept your connection.

Is there somebody here to help me out?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/,https://certbot.eff.org/, https://www.win-acme.com/, https://certifytheweb.com/

Comment: First you need to purchase a valid SSL certificate, when choosing a certificate, consider the following: Do you want end users to be able to verify your server's identity with your certificate? If yes, then either create a certificate request and send that request to a known certificate authority (CA) such as VeriSign or GeoTrust, or obtain a certificate from an online CA in your intranet domain.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you're having, you need to obtain a valid SSL certificate for your public domain. You need to complete the following steps:

1. Purchase a valid SSL certificate
2. Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
3. Submit the CSR to the certificate authority
4. Install the SSL certificate in IIS
5. Bind an SSL certificate to your website

For more details, you can refer to the link below:

[Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) in Windows IIS 10](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/generate-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-in-iis-10/#)

[Install an SSL/TLS Certificate in Windows IIS 10](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/install-an-ssl-tls-certificate-in-iis-10/)

[Binding in Windows IIS 10](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/binding-in-iis-10/)